# Get entities that have been only locally removed (not saved)?

Tags: entity-framework

I'm doing a "Preview" action so that you can preview your changes on edits before doing them. Effectively what I'm doing is calling the update function (not action) without saving.

**Update function code-bits:**

```
// Updates existing schedules to new values; Working
UpdateSchedules(...); 

// Removes existing schedules no longer in date-range; Not working
RemoveSchedules(...); 
{
   ...
   foreach(schedule in schedulesToRemove) { db.Entry(schedule).State = EntityState.Deleted; }
   db.Schedules.RemoveRange(...);
   ...
}

// Adds schedules new to date-range; Working
AddSchedules(...); 
{
    ...
    db.Schedules.Add(...);
    ...
}
```

**Retrieval Code:**

```
// The results have the modified and added entities, but they also have the removed entities.
viewModel.Results = db.PaymentRecurringSchedules.Where(s => s.PaymentSetupHeaderID == headerID).OrderBy(s => s.PaymentDate).ToList();
```

My intention with this code is to not call `db.SaveChanges()` since it's just a preview, but I still want only the schedules that weren't removed (saved or unsaved).

**What I've tried**

- I tried changing the state of the removed items as you can see above.
- I tried doing a `.Where(s => db.Entry(s).State != EntityState.Deleted)` it didn't like that at all (i.e. execution errors).

How can I get the results where the items I removed but are unsaved will still be filtered out of the results list?

**Version:** 6.0 *(In case it matters)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't have VS at hand, but i think that this should work as you requested:

```
List<Object> deletedEntities = context.ChangeTracker.Entries()
 .Where(x => x.State == System.Data.EntityState.Deleted)
 .Select(x => x.Entity)
 .ToList();
```

Take care that you may want to filter also to specific Entity type/s.